# Transfer a MongoDB database over an unstable connection

Tags: mongodb

I have a fairly small MongoDB instance (15GB) running on my local machine, but I need to push it to a remote server in order for my partner to work on it. The problem is twofold,

1. The server only has 30GB of free space
2. My local internet connection is very unstable

I tried `copyDatabase` to transfer it directly, but it would take approximately 2 straight days to finish, in which the connection is almost guaranteed to fail at some point. I have also tried both `mongoexport` and `mongodump` but both produce files that are ~40GB, which won't fit on the server, and that's ignoring the difficulties of transferring 40GB in the first place.

Is there another, more stable method that I am unaware of?

Comment: Not an answer but a choice, you can split the database into pieces of less than 1GB data and send it. If it's important, you may make a snapshot for the disk and copy the snapshot to a new disk, and send it to your partner

Comment: @JohnZeng We both need to be able to mutate the data and see the changes, repeatedly copying and deleting the entire DB is an option, but not one I would like to use

Comment: But the splitting idea isn't bad

Comment: I think you holp to work on the same database. Maybe you can upload them  to a cloud service? Like AWS, you can send your hard disk to them and they will help you to import the data, and then you can access to the database on cloud.

Comment: @JohnZeng That is a brilliantly out of the box solution, but unfortunately we are both on a tight  budget and a tight schedule, thanks anyway

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using? Since your `mongodump` output is larger than your data, I'm assuming you are using MongoDB 3.0+ with the WiredTiger storage engine and your data is compressed but your `mongodump` output is not. In MongoDB 3.2+ the `mongodump` and `mongorestore` tools have support for compression (see: [Archiving and Compression in MongoDB Tools](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/archiving-and-compression-in-mongodb-tools)). I'd suggest using 3.2 `mongodump --gzip` to create a compressed backup and then `rsync -aP` for a (resumable) download over your unstable connection.

Comment: @Stennie That could totally be an answer, it is MongoDB 3.2

Comment: @ChuckFulminata Cool .. just wanted to confirm the guess :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your `mongodump` output is much larger than your data, I'm assuming you are using MongoDB 3.0+ with the WiredTiger storage engine and your data is compressed but your `mongodump` output is not.

As at MongoDB 3.2, the `mongodump` and `mongorestore` tools now have support for compression (see: [Archiving and Compression in MongoDB Tools](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/archiving-and-compression-in-mongodb-tools)). Compression is not used by default.

For your use case as described I'd suggest:

- Use `mongodump --gzip` to create a `dump` directory with compressed backups of all of your collections.
- Use [`rsync --partial SRC .... DEST`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) or similar for a (resumable) file transfer over your unstable internet connection.

  **NOTE:** There may be some directories you can tell `rsync` to ignore with `--exclude`; for example the `local` and `test` databases can probably be skipped. Alternatively, you may want to specify a database to backup with `mongodump --gzip --db dbname`.
- Your partner can use a similar `rsync` commandline to transfer to their environment, and a command line like `mongorestore --gzip /path/to/backup` to populate their local MongoDB instance.
- If you are going to transfer dumps on an ongoing basis, you will probably find `rsync`'s `--checksum` option useful to include. Normally `rsync` transfers "updated" files based on a quick comparison of file size and modification time. A checksum involves more computation but would allow skipping collections that have identical data to previous backups (aside from the modification time).

If you need to sync data changes on ongoing basis, you also may be better moving your database to a cloud service (eg. a Database-as-a-Service provider like MongoDB Atlas or your own MongoDB instance).